# Mass Emailing based on event day and time

Tags: civievent, email

I have read different resources, but still can't determine the best way to email all attendees registered for a specific event date and time the day prior or the day of the event.

I'm sure this can be done but not sure of the correct steps.  Does a group have to be created each time, can it be automated???

Thanks,

E

Answer (score 2):

You can use [schedule reminders](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/) to send notifications based on event dates and status

Comment: Is there a way to un-dither the option that shows under configure - I can see Schedule Reminders but it is dithered and I can't select it

Comment: @epauldc29 I'm not sure where you're looking, but try **Administer menu >> Communications >> Scheduled Reminders** and you should have better luck.

Comment: When I go into Manage Events and scroll through my events there are options to the right for each event: Configure, Participants, Events Links, and More.  When you hover over Configure a list pops up with the option to Schedule Reminders, but that option is dithered out.  Here is a link to the screenshot: <img src="https://pasteboard.co/JYmGuSV.png" width="100" height="100">.